# Android Multi module with air

Tags: android, gradle

I have multimode android project like below.

```
:module A
:module B
```

and module A have dependency on aar file `SDK.aar`

So in Module A build.gradle file I referenced like this, and I add SDK.aar in moduleA/libs folder.

`implementation(name: 'SDK.arr', ext: 'arr')`

And module B have dependency on Module A, so in Module B build.gradle,

`implementation project(":moduleA")`

When I try build, error throws like this.

```
Execution failed for task ':publish:dataBindingMergeGenClassesDevDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':moduleB:devDebugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find :SDK:.
 Required by:
     project :moduleB > project :moduleA
```

When I add SDK.aar to moduleB/libs folder, that error removed.

But SDK.aar is only used by module A, so I don't want to add arr in Module B.

Is there any way to resolve that error?

Comment: Try to change implementation(name: 'SDK.arr', ext: 'arr') -> api(name: 'SDK.arr', ext: 'arr')

Comment: Thanks, but it still fails.